Definecolor transparent background
How to define a definecolor in rgb or HTML that has a transparent background but is blurry is latex (overleaf)

there are several answers if you follow the transparency tag link showing how to handle transparency in latex

It is unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want a color or do you want a blurry overlay? And if the latter, how should the result look like?

Welcome to TeX.SE \pagecolor{...colorname...} may be a choice, but nothing able to understand from your post, please make it more clear
